# Calculation in sql select query

Tags: sql

I have the following query

```
select 
t.column1,
t.column2
t.column1 * t.column2 as 'Multiply'
from test t
```

So I need to use the **'Multiple'** Column values in the further expression
like

```
  'Multiply' * getData('value1','value2','value3')---
```

One way is to use same values to get the data like

```
t.column1 * t.column2 * getData('value1','value2','value3')
```

Any other way to do this??

I don't want to write too many columns If there are multiple columns in the future.

Comment: See `cross apply` / `lateral join`